# Crawled Properties from Business Data not getting created

Tags: 2007, crawling, external-content-type, fast-search, business-data-catalog

I have created a content source crawling exteranl data using business data connectivity service. I can sucessfully crawl the business data content source without any errors. In crawl logs also I didn't get any errors, but crawled properties are not getting created. I checked the crawled properties under Business Data category but there are no properties matching my external database columns. Can anyone help me on this?